# More pythonic way to iterate through two lists switching directions after every line?

Tags: python, iteration, nested-lists

I am writing some code that loops through two lists in a bit of an odd fashion. My goal is to iterate through all of list `a`, using index `i`, then loop through `b` using index `j` and alternate back and forth. I.e. I want to iterate through pairs in the order:

```
(0,0),...,(n,0),(0,1)...(0,m),(1,1)...,(n,1),(1,2)...,(1,m),(2,2),...,(n,m)
```

My current code is written like this:

```
while i+j < len(a) + len(b) -2:
    #do stuff
    if direction_toggle:
        if i + 1 > len(a):
            direction_toggle = not direction_toggle
            i = j
        else:
            i += 1
    else:
        if j + 1 > len(b):
            direction_toggle = not direction_toggle
            j = i + 1
        else:
            j += 1
```

However, I would like to be a bit more pythonic, and follow the maxim of

> Flat is better than nested.

What I want to write something that looks more like this:

```
while i+j < len(a) + len(b) -2:
    #do stuff
    if direction_toggle:
        var, length = i, len(a)
    else:
        var, length = j, len(b)
    if var + 1 > length:
        direction_toggle = not direction_toggle
    else:
        var += 1
```

So my question is: is there a way to accomplish the same goal but be less repetitive, and remove a layer of nesting? Broadly, my code is pretty simple but it seems that there's no way to avoid repeating myself in two different ways, am I missing something, or is my implementation in fact the bast way to accomplish this?

PS I hope this isn't a duplicate, I couldn't find any other questions addressing 
this theme.

EDIT FOR CLARITY: My specific requirement is that I process `(i, j-1)`, `(i-1, j)` and `(i-1, j-1)` before hitting `(i, j)`. Any possible path of iteration satisfying this requirement will work. In case you're interested, this is because I am trying to implement a DTW algorithm, where each value assigned in a matrix depends on previous adjacent values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you lay out the numbers in an n-row by m-column grid, you can obtain your solution by walking down the first column, then across the first row (starting at column 1), then down the second column (starting at row 1), then across the second row (starting at column 2), then down the third column (starting at row 2), etc. This simply implements that.

```
def gen_tuples(n_rows, n_cols):
    row = col = 0
    while row <= n_rows and col <= n_cols:
        for i in range(row, n_rows + 1):
            yield (i, col)

        for j in range(col + 1, n_cols + 1):
            yield (row, j)

        row += 1
        col += 1


list(gen_tuples(5, 3))

[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 0),
 (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3),
 (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1),
 (1, 2), (1, 3),
 (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 2),
 (2, 3),
 (3, 3), (4, 3), (5, 3)]
```

Comment: While your solution addresses my issue, I'm looking for something a bit different. For me, this would mean playing with the `#do this` part, and moving it into a function call, which probably ends up more messy than my original. So iterating in series like you suggest is not really the answer for me, I think the only way for my code to work is to increment the relevant variable *after* `#do this`. I however appreciate the solution, it looks pretty neat!

Comment: @Mathchiller What about "beautiful is better than ugly", "simple is better than complex", and "readability counts"?

Comment: I guess you're right, I could `gen_tuples` and then iterate through that list.

Comment: I think you should change the `and` to an `or`, in order to also get `(5,3)`, which currently is excluded.

Comment: @Mathchiller See my update -- I changed `<` to `<=`

Answer (score 0):

## Per your "EDIT FOR CLARITY"

> My specific requirement is that I process (i, j-1), (i-1, j) and (i-1, j-1) before hitting (i, j).

That can just be done by

```
for i in range(n + 1):
    for j in range(m + 1):
         do_stuff()
```

---

If I understand correctly this time, if this was a 5 x 4 (n = 4, m = 3) matrix you basically want the below order:

```
 0 5  6  7
 1 8  12 13
 2 9  14 17
 3 10 15 18
 4 11 16 19
```

You should be able to solve this recursively.

```
def stripes(r, c, r0=0, c0=0, flip=False):
    for row in range(r0, r + 1):
        yield (row, c0) if not flip else (c0, row)
    if r0 <= r:
        yield from stripes(c, r, r0=c0 + 1, c0=r0, flip=not flip)
```

And then:

```
>>> list(stripes(4, 3))
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0),
 (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3),
 (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1),
 (1, 2), (1, 3),
 (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2),
 (2, 3),
 (3, 3), (4, 3)]
```

or for your specific use case:

```
cache = {}
for r, c in stripes(R, C):
    inputs = (r - 1, c), (r - 1, c - 1), (r, c - 1)
    a, b, c = (cache.get((x, y)) for x, y in inputs)
    cache[(r, c)] = do_stuff(a, b, c)
```

Comment: I guess I should edit my question to clarify and be more specific (which I will do in a minute). However, your solution does not solve my issue. I have the requirement that I process `i, j-1`, `i-1, j` and `i-1, j-1` before reaching `i, j`. your solution fails at this criteria, since it hits `(3,1)` before `(2,1)`.

Comment: Ah!  I misunderstood then!